# Is "contentual" a proper word?

Tags: meaning, etymology, adjectives, is-it-a-word

Is *contentual* a proper word? I saw in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contentual) that it is considered to be a proper word:

> *contentual*
>
> adjective
>
> Relating to content (as apposed to context)

However, I have not seen it cited in any major dictionaries (Websters, Oxford, Collins etc.).

If the reason it is not in these dictionaries is because the word *"contentual"* is not considered to be a proper word, why is this so?

Comment: Wiktionary does not have an editorial policy to be a repository of definitions of proper words. Which is to say if a 'word' is in Wiktionary, there is no guarantee that it is recognizable with a consistent meaning by most people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the OED, so I'd say it is a word, albeit not a very common one:

> *Philos*. and *Psychol.*
>
> Belonging to, or dealing with, content (opp. act or form).

The citations listed are from 1909 to 1962. (I'm not sure when this entry was last updated though.)

Comment: Does the OED give a date for its first use? I frequently find that what I see as a new word was used by somebody in, say,  1563. But if it strikes me, as a reasonably well read native speaker of English, as new, then it has not been a great success as a word.

Comment: Apparently, the mathematician [Hilbert](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/11192) has also appropriated the term in a specialist usage. [McLarty; University of Oxford Mathematical Institute.]

Comment: Abstract adjectives never really die. They just lie quiescent until they're needed for some new abstruse argument.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ... Note Hilbert used the German word "inhaltlich" (meaning: in terms of content), and philosophers translated it using their own English jargon word "contentual".

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition of "a proper word"? It strikes me as a **new** word, so new that it is unusual. If it is new it is not surprising that it has not made its way into the dictionaries that you mention.

In time it may become a word that we all use without a second thought. But it is not there yet.

So, unless you particularly feel the need for this word, or have a particular liking for it, do not use it. Wait and see. If it serves a useful purpose it may survive. If not, not.

Comment: Note the difference between this answer, conjecture, and Laurel's, based on a solid reference work (with quote and attribution). Answers on ELU should be more than guesswork / opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan Bauer-Mengelberg proposed 'contentual' as a translation of the German 'inhaltlich' (*J. Symbol. Log.*, v. 31 (1966), p. 489), a word used by logicians and philosophers. B-M thought he was coining a new word. As pointed out above, he wasn't. The on-line OED quotes four uses, the oldest from 1909, as mentioned above; it's from a book called *Valuation: Its Nature and Laws* by W. M. Urban (described by Wikipedia as an American philosopher of language, influenced by Ernst Cassirer).