# (Adj) Word for "Related to the content" of media, rather than related to the medium

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm talking about the different problems related to the experience of watching lecture videos.

- Certain problems such as video resolution or audio quality are technological.
- Other problems are related to the content of the videos, such as incorrect information being taught, or long periods of action without speaking (ie writing on the board).

How can I describe the latter problem? I'm leaning towards ***contentual***, from [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439264/is-contentual-a-proper-word) with the following definition:

> contentual
>
> adjective
>
> Relating to content (as apposed to context)

The answer to that question says 'contentual' is in the OED, but I haven't been able to find it.

**Can I use 'contentual'? If not, what adjective should I use?**

Comment: It's not clear to me how *contextual* does ***not*** relate to the content. And while *contentual* might exist as a word in some places, it would be so uncommon as to look strange to most people who read it. It might be understood, but it would likely be perceived as a mistake or a sign of poor English. (Unless first used in italics, scare quotes, or some other style that indicates you know you're using a thought-to-be-made-up word.)

Comment: Your two examples are of _factual errors_ and _stylistic shortcomings_. In my opinion these are so different from each other as to warrant the consideration of three aspects of video lectures. Factual errors are the most serious as they result in the transmission of what is not true, technical and presentational shortcomings merely make the transmission of the information less effective.

Comment: Please provide at least one (the more, the better) sample sentences in which you would use this adjective. Also, why do you think you can't use *contentual*? Have you looked at how it's used [in published literature](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=contentual)?

Comment: @Jason Bassford 'Contextual' relates to context, internal and external. OP wants a hyponym.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to say

**content-related**

but I'm not sure, because you didn't show us how you'd like to use the word in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a late response, so I imagine you don't need it anymore, but perhaps "substantive" might work? You could use a word like that, or even "contentual" as you say, and the first time it is used say something in parentheses to clarify its meaning for the future.

> The difference between A and B is *substantive* (as opposed to superficial or contextual) and so the solution to B's problem is not to simply change the format, but rather to adjust its thesis.

Comment: I'd take 'substantive' here in what I believe to be its default sense, 'major / non-trivial', and so would find this confusing if not accompanied by 'as opposed to contextual'. But welcome to ELU; please take 'the tour' and get a feel for the standard of answer really appreciated on ELU (accompanied by linked, attributed references, hopefully with parallel examples).