# What is an English adjective describing properties related to the content

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

Is there any single-word adjective that emphasizes the property is related to the ***content*** opposed to the properties that are related to the ***container***?

I have seen the word ***contentual*** which does not seem to be very common.

To clarify my intent, consider a container that holds liquid.
consider the weight of the compound, it is mostly related to the content so, you may say:

> weight is a *contentual* property

on the other hand, the volume, is mostly related to the container, so, it is not a *contentual* property.

I am looking for a word to replace *contentual* in the above sentences

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate - [Is "contentual" a proper word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439264/is-contentual-a-proper-word) It's in the full OED, so maybe you should just use that term. Alternatively, perhaps ***content-based*** (as opposed to ***format-based***, which in most contexts would be equivalent to "relating to the **medium / container** rather than the **message / content**").

Comment: In the OED, "contentual" is restricted to the fields of philosophy and psychology and is defined as *" Belonging to, or dealing with, content (opposed to act or form)"* - which is not what you want. In your context,  "contentual property" would be better expressed as "a property of the contents". However, as it does not include the container, the phrase would be "the major factor in the weight." (Probably "mass" would be better than "weight".)

Answer (score 2):

> (Nett) weight is a **content-related / content-bound property**.

I would avoid *contentual*, unless you define it for your readers. The things described in the OED citations seem more abstract than physical. There is no adjective such as **containeral* that would come to mind to help grasp the meaning of *contentual*, and it might even be confused with *contentious*.

You say "...consider the weight of the compound, it is **mostly** related to the content...". In fact, we distinguish gross, nett, tare,  and volumetric weight.  *Nett* weight is a property of the contents. Both the container and its contents have weight/a weight.

We also say the container has a certain (maximum) volume; its contents occupy all or a fraction of it. Both the container and its contents have volume/a volume.

If you need to distinguish, I suggest:

**container-related properties**
and
**content-related properties**

An alternative would be **content-bound** and **container-bound** properties.

You could also use *content* and *container* attributively: "X is a **content property** and Y is a **container property**."